# Views Conditional Fields According to Devices

Tags: 7, views

Does views allows to render fields according to device. For example is there a possibility to load field a if website is loading on iphone, load field b if device is loading on android.

or

load field 1 if website is loading on smart phones, load field 2 if tab and load field 3 if desktop.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, I don't think views supports this. But you can use the [Mobile Detect](https://www.drupal.org/project/mobile_detect)  module to achieve this. Note: you need to download the mobile detect library as well and place it in the module folder as specified in ReadMe.txt
Then you can use either of the below preprocess functions to detect the device and then return your output to the views template.

template_preprocess_views_view

template_preprocess_views_view_fields

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create different views and in your template file use a code like this:

```
switch($device){
      case "device1":
           print views_embed_view("VIEW_NAME","PAGE_1");
           break;
      case "device2":
           print views_embed_view("VIEW_NAME","PAGE_2");
           break;
      case "device3":
           print views_embed_view("VIEW_NAME","PAGE_3");
           break;
      case "device4":
           print views_embed_view("VIEW_NAME","PAGE_4");
           break;
}
```